# Ubuntu Upgrade Issue

Tags: server, upgrade

I had an old server with 16.04 and Russian console.
I decided to change the console to English during the upgrade to the 18.04.1 and was fail to agree to remove about 400 old packets from the system.
System was waiting for the Cyrillic respond,but I had only English character set by this moment.
Now I can not install any new software because of the dependency issues.
I was fail to upgrade to 20.04 also.
Can you advise me how to fix that?

Best Regards,
Konstantin

Comment: My suggestion is that you get all the config and data off of the computer and do a fresh install in English. Please specify what server you are trying to install and what GUI you intend on using.

Comment: What exactly are the "dependency issues"?  Please edit your question with the full output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`.  Please retain formatting and line breaks by putting four spaces at the beginning of each line.

Comment: @Nmath: Another way to format lines of computer speak is to: Cut and Paste the text; Select the text; Click on the `{}` icon.